# MySQL UNION query return duplicate values even using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        m.id AS id,
        reference_id, 
        title, 
        created_by, 
        publish_up, 
        state 
    FROM z_news_master m  
    LEFT JOIN z_news_english c ON m.id = c.reference_id
    WHERE c.created_by = 17152
    ORDER by c.id DESC
) AS A

UNION

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        m.id AS id, 
        reference_id,
        title, 
        created_by, 
        publish_up, 
        state 
    FROM z_news_master m  
    LEFT JOIN z_news_spanish c ON m.id = c.reference_id
    WHERE c.created_by = 17152
    ORDER by c.id DESC 
) AS B
GROUP BY id
```

Basically, I have 3 tables (`z_news_master, z_news_english, z_news_spanish`), to store News in Spanish or English languages. The `z_news_master` table contains the generic news information, the `z_news_english` and `z_news_spanish` contain the news in its respective language.

I need to get a list of the news, if the news is in both language tables it should return only one (not duplicated), the code above does the work, but if there is a new in English and Spanish, the record gets duplicated.

I'd also like to know why the `GROUP BY id` and the `GROUP BY reference_id` don't work?

Comment: The group by applies only to the 2nd query, not to the results of the union.

Comment: Instead of a union, left join both the English and Spanish tables. In the columns, you can use CASE to determine which columns to return based on the availability of the data from those two tables. Do all of the tables have the same structure?

Comment: Post sample data and expected result. Use table (alias) prefix for all columns in the query - we can't guess where they come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a NOT EXISTS subquery to remove a fallback language row if a corresponding row for the prefered language exists. Assuming the prefered language is "english", the query would be:

```
SELECT 
    m.id AS id,
    reference_id, 
    title, 
    created_by, 
    publish_up, 
    state 
FROM z_news_master m  
JOIN z_news_english c ON m.id = c.reference_id
WHERE c.created_by = 17152

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    m.id AS id, 
    reference_id,
    title, 
    created_by, 
    publish_up, 
    state 
FROM z_news_master m  
JOIN z_news_spanish c ON m.id = c.reference_id
WHERE c.created_by = 17152
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM z_news_english e
    WHERE e.reference_id = m.id
      AND e.created_by = c.created_by
  )

ORDER by id DESC
```

Note that there is no need for GROUP BY. And a LEFT JOIN doesn't make sense because you have a WHERE condition on a column from the right table (which would convert the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using a union. The statement below gets all rows from the master table, and join any existing rows from both the spanish and english tables.
If a row exists in the spanish table, it uses the values from that table. If a row exists in the english table, and not the spanish table, it uses the values from that table.
If no matching row exists in either the english or spanish table, it returns columns from the master table.

You can alter the priorities by changing the order of the WHEN's.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT s.id IS NULL THEN s.id 
        WHEN NOT e.id IS NULL THEN e.id 
        ELSE m.id AS `id`, 
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT s.reference_id IS NULL THEN s.reference_id 
        WHEN NOT e.reference_id IS NULL THEN e.reference_id 
        ELSE m.reference_id AS `reference_id`, 
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT s.title IS NULL THEN s.title 
        WHEN NOT e.title IS NULL THEN e.title 
        ELSE m.title AS `title`, 
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT s.created_by IS NULL THEN s.created_by 
        WHEN NOT e.created_by IS NULL THEN e.created_by 
        ELSE m.created_by AS `created_by`, 
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT s.publish_up IS NULL THEN s.publish_up 
        WHEN NOT e.publish_up IS NULL THEN e.publish_up 
        ELSE m.publish_up AS `publish_up`, 
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT s.state IS NULL THEN s.state 
        WHEN NOT e.state IS NULL THEN e.state 
        ELSE m.state AS `state`
FROM z_news_master m  
LEFT JOIN z_news_spanish s ON m.id = s.reference_id
LEFT JOIN z_news_english e ON m.id = e.reference_id
WHERE m.created_by = 17152
ORDER by m.id DESC 
GROUP BY m.id
```

**EDIT**

Per *Paul Spiegel's* comment here's an even shorter version:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(s.id, e.id, m.id) AS `id`, 
    COALESCE(s.reference_id, e.reference_id, m.reference_id) AS `reference_id`, 
    COALESCE(s.title, e.title, m.title) AS `title`, 
    COALESCE(s.created_by, e.created_by, m.created_by) AS `created_by`, 
    COALESCE(s.publish_up, e.publish_up, m.publish_up) AS `publish_up`, 
    COALESCE(s.state, e.state, m.state) AS `state`
FROM z_news_master m  
LEFT JOIN z_news_spanish s ON m.id = s.reference_id
LEFT JOIN z_news_english e ON m.id = e.reference_id
WHERE m.created_by = 17152
ORDER by m.id DESC 
GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: You cann replace all your CASE statements with COALESCE. E.g.:`COALESCE(s.id, e.id, m.id) as id`

Comment: Thanks, Sloan for your answer, however it does not do the job, since the WHERE condition makes reference to z_news_master.created_by, this field exist in the language tables, not in the master table